# Como fazer um requisição no Python 3 através de um proxy HTTP

Tags: python, proxy

Em Python, podemos recuperar o conteúdo de uma URL de forma bem simples:

```py
from urllib import request
response = request.urlopen('http://www.google.com.br')
```

Porém, em ambientes corporativos não podemos acessar a internet diretamente, precisamos passar por um Proxy. Como fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solução em Python 3 usando `urllib`

Pode-se criar uma requisição usando um `opener` que, por sua vez, recebe as informações de um `Proxyhandler`:

```py
from urllib import request

#configura um "opener" com um proxy
proxy  = request.ProxyHandler({"http":"proxy:8080"})
auth = request.HTTPBasicAuthHandler()
opener = request.build_opener(proxy, auth, request.HTTPHandler)

#faz uma requisição usando o "opener"
response = opener.open('http://www.google.com.br')
print(response.read().decode('ISO-8859-1'))
```

É possível ainda definir uma configuração global de proxy da seguinte forma:

```py
from urllib import request

#configura um "opener" com um proxy
proxy  = request.ProxyHandler({"http":"proxy:8080"})
auth = request.HTTPBasicAuthHandler()
opener = request.build_opener(proxy, auth, request.HTTPHandler)

#instala o "opener" globalmente
request.install_opener(opener)

#faz uma requisição genérica (sem o opener)
response = request.urlopen('http://www.google.com.br')
print(response.read().decode('ISO-8859-1'))
```

## Solução em Python 2 usando `urllib2`

Muda um pouco em relação ao Python 3, lembrando que a `urllib2` da versão 2 é "equivalente" à `urllib` da versão 3, embora funções e classes tenham mudado de local e nome:

```py
import urllib2

#proxy
proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({"http":"proxy:8080"})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

response = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.google.com")
print response.read()
```

## Solução usando a biblioteca [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)

Para adicionar o proxy em uma requisição simples:

```py
import requests

response = requests.get("http://www.google.com",
                        proxies = { "http": "proxy:8080" })
print(response.text)
```

Para adicionar o proxy em várias requisições:

```py
import requests

sessao = requests.Session()
sessao.proxies = {"http": "proxy:8080"}

response = sessao.get("http://www.google.com")
print(response.text)
```

*Nota: Lembrando que esta é uma biblioteca instalada à parte.*

---

*Nota geral: os exemplos são para um proxy HTTP que não precisa de usuário e senha.*

Answer (score 0):

Basta definir o proxy que se quer utilizar através de uma variável de ambiente. No Windows a configuração de proxy são obtidos directamente da configuração do internet explorer.

Mas depende também do tipo de proxy. Se for uma coisa tipo MS proxy server a usar NTLM para autorização, então aí vai ter de usar qualquer coisa do género:

http://code.google.com/p/python-ntlm/